# Handling date format in JSpinner with SpinDateModel

Tags: java, swing, jspinner

I have the following lines of code:

```
    SpinnerDateModel spinMod=new SpinnerDateModel();
    JSpinner spin=new JSpinner(spinMod);
    //spin.setEditor(new JSpinner.DateEditor(spin,"dd.mm.yyyy"));
```

When I display the spinner I can edit it and write in the month field any two-digit number I want.

If I click on the `JSpinner` side I can only increase and decrease the month or day numbers so that their values are legal. But, if I add the last outcommented line, this wouldn't work, either.

The question is how to make the `JSpinner` accept only legal dates with the custom format.

Also, if I make an `ActionListener` added to a button that gets the date, I get a "correct date" by applying getValue() directly to the `JSpinner`, but a wrong one (the one entered) if I apply the date editor's format to the value obtained from the `JSpinner`. I want the action listener to get the correct value in my custom format and I want the `JSpinner` to only accept input in the custom format. Is that possible?

My test code is below:

```
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
import javax.swing.*;
import javax.swing.event.*;
import java.util.*;
import java.text.*; //for the date format

public class TestDates{

    JLabel jl=new JLabel("Date:");
    JFrame jf=new JFrame("Test SpinnerDateFormat");

    JButton jb=new JButton("Get Date");
    SpinnerDateModel spinMod=new SpinnerDateModel();
    JSpinner spin=new JSpinner(spinMod);

    class jbHandler implements ActionListener{
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent evt){
            JSpinner.DateEditor de=(JSpinner.DateEditor)spin.getEditor();
            String wrongDate=de.getFormat().format(spin.getValue());
            Date okDate=(Date)spin.getValue();
            System.out.println(">>>\n"+wrongDate+"\n"+okDate);
        }
    }

    JPanel pane=new JPanel();

    public TestDates(){

        jf.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
        jf.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

        pane.add(jl);

        jb.addActionListener(new jbHandler());
        pane.add(jb);

        spin.setValue(new Date());//this doesn't work properly with the custom format
        spin.setEditor(new JSpinner.DateEditor(spin,"dd.mm.yyyy"));
        pane.add(spin);

        jf.add(pane);
        jf.pack();
        jf.setVisible(true);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args){

    SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable(){
        public void run(){
            TestDates tdate=new TestDates();
        }
        });
    }
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> *If I click on the JSpinner side I can only increase and decrease the month or day numbers so that their values are legal. But, if I add the
>   last outcommented line, this wouldn't work, either.*

The problem is a little (but pretty common) mistake in your date pattern at this line:

```
spin.setEditor(new JSpinner.DateEditor(spin,"dd.mm.yyyy"));
```

In this pattern "mm" refers to minutes not months, thus causing different outputs. The correct pattern is:

```
spin.setEditor(new JSpinner.DateEditor(spin,"dd.MM.yyyy"));
```

---

> *The question is how to make the JSpinner accept only legal dates with the custom format.*

If you want to prevent users to type invalid dates, then you need to play with editor's formatter and disallow invalid inputs. See the following snippet:

```
SpinnerDateModel model = new SpinnerDateModel();
JSpinner spinner = new JSpinner(model);

JSpinner.DateEditor editor = new JSpinner.DateEditor(spinner, "dd.MM.yyyy");
DateFormatter formatter = (DateFormatter)editor.getTextField().getFormatter();
formatter.setAllowsInvalid(false); // this makes what you want
formatter.setOverwriteMode(true);
```

---

#### Custom date-time formats

See [Customizing Formats](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/i18n/format/simpleDateFormat.html) trail.

See also the following table extracted from ***Date and Time Patterns*** section in [SimpleDateFormat](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html) javadoc:

[image]